# Does android supports multiple roots in layout xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

Here I need to combine these two roots....is it possible???
If yes then how????

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
    android:layout_width="match_parent"`
    android:layout_height="match_parent"`
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`
    android:gravity="center_vertical"`
    android:orientation="vertical">`
</LinearLayout>`

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"`
    android:layout_width="match_parent"`
    android:background="#ffffff"`
    android:layout_height="match_parent">`

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"`
        android:layout_width="240dp"`
        android:layout_height="match_parent"`
        android:layout_gravity="left"`
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"`
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"`
        android:clickable="true"`
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>`

</`android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`>`
```

Comment: i don't think so and what you try to archive??

Comment: i need to integrate some layouts with drawer layouts, that why..

Comment: so no need to 2 root layout its senseless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML standard does not allow to add multiple root elements in xml document. So I do not think that any app which works with XML will support multiple root elements when it is not allowed by XML standard.

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/WHITE"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/sliding_menu_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_menu_module_list_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that. When inserting a DrawerLayout, you have to provide a layout for the main content view and then a layout for the drawer.
For example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/sliding_menu_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_menu_module_list_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```