# ScrollView refuses to scroll

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to use `ScrollView` and `NavDrawer` in same `Activity`. Everything's placed fine but I'm unable to scroll. I'm able to get `NavDrawer` and `ScrollView` side by side as I wanted but I'm not able to scroll. The screen is fixed , though the scrollbar is there on the screen but it's no scrolling up or down.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="4dp"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="4dp"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="4dp"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="4dp"></FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">



        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
             android:id="@+id/nav_view"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="start"
             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
             app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_homepage1"
             app:menu="@menu/activity_homepage1_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: There seems to be something wrong here. You have two roots views i.e `ScrollView` and the `DrawerLayout` in the same file. This is not allowed. You can only have one root view in an xml file.http://stackoverflow.com/a/24867692/5512274

Comment: So then how to add DrawerLayout and ScrollView in the same activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="4dp"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="4dp"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="4dp"></FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="4dp"></FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">



        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
             android:id="@+id/nav_view"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="start"
             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
             app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_homepage1"
             app:menu="@menu/activity_homepage1_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As soon I launch it crashes.

Comment: Mmmmmm the problem is that am away form my desktop right now and am posting from my phone.

Comment: When i reach my desktop if your problem was not solved yet i will post